# Include another file in PHP class

Tags: php, include

I'm sure this has been asked a few times, but I can't seem to find a straight forward or well explained answer. I'm attempting to create a Account Object/Class within PHP, where I can retrieve data from an account. The issue I'm having is that I cannot include my database.php class so I can retrieve all the created accounts.

I'm fairly new with PHP and don't have an expansive knowledge on how a lot of the processes or conventions work. The error/warning I'm running into is this;

> Warning: include(../database.php): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in ~/account.php on line 3

Here is my account.php class

```
<?php

include '../database.php';

class Account {

    protected $username, $email;

    protected function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    protected function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function __construct($username, $email) {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public static function getUser($username) {
        $statement = getConnection()->prepare('SELECT * FROM account WHERE username=?');
        $statement->bindValue(1, $username);

        if ($rows = $statement->fetch()) {
             $account = new Account($rows['username'], $rows['email']);
        }

         return $account;
    }

}
```

Here is my database.php incase I've done something wrong or may need to change things

```
<?php

function getConnection() {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mcsl;port3306", "root", "");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    return $dbh;
}
```

Directory Structure:

[image: Directory Structure]

Comment: Directory May Not Be Correct.

Comment: Where is `account.php` * `database.php` pages saved.

Comment: According to your error, your path for your `database.php` file is incorrect.

Comment: @NanaPartykar I thought the same, but I'm using the same include function in another php file in the same directory, and it's working fine.

Comment: Can you please post your directory structure for account.php, database.php page.

Comment: @NanaPartykar The account.php is located in php/user/account.php and database.php is located in php/database.php

Comment: Do `include '../../database.php';`

Comment: @NanaPartykar Same error, cannot find directory

Comment: Is it working in create-account.php page? Check it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `include (dirname(__FILE__)."/../database.php")` to access the database.php file in the account.php file

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

You currently have a mix of object-oriented and procedural code.

Adding database features to a class is normally accomplished by dependency injection. In other words, you pass the database object as argument to whatever method needs it and use type hinting to enforce it, e.g.:

```
public static function getUser(MyConnectionClassOrInterface $db, $username) {
}
```

As about your include, you're using relative paths, which are relative to *main script*, not current file. You can build absolute paths or use a more elaborate class auto-loader.

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for the include problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory