# require_once does not work using a correct path

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I'm having a problem with the `require_once` function.

When I call the function `require_once("/a/b/c/d/e.php");`, the function crashes although the path is correct for the file.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: `/a/b/c/d/e.php` is an absolute Path. Are you sure you want to use an absolute path and not a relative one?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: No need to add just `/` at the start, If want to add then add like `./`. In your case `require_once("./a/b/c/d/e.php");` OR `require_once("a/b/c/d/e.php");`

Comment: If the path was correct it wouldn't "crash". 1) Convince us why you think the path is correct. 2) Give us the concrete error you're seeing.

Comment: share both path `path of file which need to be include` and `path of file where you are using this code` ?

Comment: i tried using a relative path by using $DirAct = getcwd(); $DirPrincipal = dirname(dirname($DirAct)); $DirPrincipal= $DirPrincipal."/www/motlle/gen.php"; but it also crashed the path of the files is /home/projei/www/resp/test.php for my actual and /home/projei/www/mot/gen.php for the one i have to include  and i know their paths becouse i'm editing them via notepad++ and i'm using it as reference

Comment: and for the error i d'ont recive any message it's just blank and i know the code from gen.php is correct because i have alredy tested it before thats the reason i don't know what to do

Comment: You don't receive *any* error?! Then start by **enabling error reporting** and/or looking at your error logs. Poking around in the dark helps neither us nor you.

Comment: the errors are activated and i still don't recive anything, i tried creating an error and it is displayed thats why i find it so strange

Comment: may be apache configuration or permissions is not set correctly

Comment: Must be i uninstaled apache and re-instaled and it worked thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

[Include another file in PHP class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528789/include-another-file-in-php-class/37529218#37529218)

try `require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/a/b/c/d/e.php")`